# SQL one to many from many to many relation

Tags: sql, one-to-many

I'm trying to figure out SQL query that will list only one to many relation

Below Table contain 11 records where i would like to return two line with Field1 = 7 (one to many)

Table1:

```
Field1  Field2  
1   a   
2   a   
3   b   
4   b   
5   c   
4   d   exclude 4 and 6 as d is linked to both

6   d   
6   e   
7   f   One to Many
7   j   One to Many
8   g
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want all the `field2` values to appear once for each `field1`.  Here is a method using window functions:

```
select field1
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by field2) as num_field2
      from t
     ) t
group by field1
having count(*) > 1 and max(num_field2) = 1;
```